# How to deploy asp.net 4.5 identity server application to azure with signing certificates

Tags: c#, azure, ssl-certificate, identityserver3

I have c# asp.net 4.5 identityserver v3 web application. I am using this as my authorization server. I am using the default sample signing certificates as mentioned in [Default Signing Certificates](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Certificates)

Now i want to deploy this in to azure. I am a newbie to this azure hosting.

Can anyone please help me how to deploy this webapp to azure with these certificates?

I tried with the following code. The thumbprint is the certificate i uploaded to azure website.

```
public X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string filename, string password)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                                    "6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CCd091FAAE1",
                                                    false);
    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        cert = certCollection[0];
    }

    if(cert == null)
    {
        var path = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}{filename}";
        cert = new X509Certificate2(path, password);
    }

    return cert;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone please help me how to deploy this webapp to azure with these certificates?

If you want to install these certificates under the CurrentUser. You could [upload the .pfx  to the Azure WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#upload-your-ssl-certificate) from Azure portal and add an app setting called **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES**

> Add an app setting called WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES and set its value to the thumbprint of the certificate. To make multiple certificates accessible, use comma-separated thumbprint values. To make all certificates accessible, set the value to *.